# Android Webview net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: android, webview, android-styles

Could you give me a hand? I have a WebView display page, and when I click on buttons like (Join our telegra channel or share articles via Whatsapp and other social networks) this error appears: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

I kindly ask you for some advice as I have tried several suggestions but without results

This is my code

````
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://myurl");
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //Swipe to refresh functionality
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);


        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        webView.reload();
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public class Mainactiv extends WebViewClient{


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack())
        {
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

replace shouldOverrideUrlLoading with this:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
    if(url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("whatsapp:")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it does not work :(